# Overloading in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, overloading

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822929/method-over-loading-in-homecontroller-and-routing-issue-in-asp-net-mvc) that I can't overload actions in MVC because of routing confusion
I tried to overload Index() in HomeController and I got the exception as article said, but I noticed that
microsoft has overloaded the actions in AccountController

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl){}
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl){}
```

Please need clarification, thanks

Comment: Check this link about overloading.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078543/c-sharp-mvc-3-action-overloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till today you **cannot** overload your controller's **Action method with same name but different parameters**.

The only possibility is to have two overload, and for that you need to set the method's property to `HttpGet` and `HttpPost`. For example

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult foo(string myString)
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult foo(MyViewModelClass object)
{
   return View();
}
```

And regarding your confusion,

From general convention, first method should be of type `Get` which gets called when someone sends request to access that page.

Second method is called when user submits a form with his login details.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has overloaded this by setting `HttpGet` and `HttpPost`. One for GET request and another for POST request. What about your code?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl){}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl){}
```

Answer (score 0):

In AccountController first method works with GET method, second with POST one. It was realized by attribute `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]`.

Read more about get and post **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)**.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer we can add name attributes along with HTTPGET and HTTPPOST as

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit_Post(some parameters)
{
//code over here
 }
After this we can call it as :- /MVC/EmployeeController/Edit/1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some definitions first:**

1. `Overloading` is a form of polymorphism, in     particular an interface, in the sense of a class publicly visible part,  related one.
2. When we speak about inheritance we mean `overriding`.
3. Action is a segment of a URL.

**Back to your question...** 
It is the `ControllerActionInvoker` which is responsible for finding the method to which an action is mapped. Given GET and POST we see polymorphic methods in a class mapped to the same action, but serving different HTTP methods (any action, that is, URL segment polymorphism here?!). And again yes, we may use `ActionNameAttribute` (MVC v5) to map an action to a class method, but again, this has nothing to do with any sort of polymorphism. Simply put, all that happens is in the `ControllerActionInvoker` and has nothing to do with `overloading` or `overriding`, and finally with any sort of polymorphism -- it is just mapping.

**Conclusion.**
A simple question arises:

**What in a string (a segment of a URL, 3.) relates to any one of the OOP definitions (1. and 2.) above? Or, in other words, can any of the OOP concepts above be *transformed* to a (part of a) string?**

The fact that a transformation between URL segment, which happen to be called "action", and a class method exits **does not imply** that all we know about the first mechanically can be applied to the second and vice-verse. The question is misleading and its main intention is to confuse someone, not to test his/her knowledge (I suspect that this is an artificial interview questions, not a real one).